# SSH с двумя IP, как это называется?

Tags: ssh

Заказчик (ИТ отдел) предоставил SSH-доступ вот такого вида:

```
ssh server_user_name@server_address@server_address
```

Через командную строку все ок, но я хочу подключаться через bitvise ssh, подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое подключение называется? Или как подключиться через bitvise ssh?

Comment: `server_user_name@server_address` — это имя пользователя.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , да, точно, спасибо! напишите как ответ, я выберу его